# Using NetBeans for Python GUI development

Tags: python, netbeans

Is NetBeans recommended for developing a GUI for a Python app?

Does it have a form/screen builder for Python apps, like Dabo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it isn't "built-in" to Netbeans, I've found Qt Designer to be an excellent tool for building GUIs for Python. Of course, this only works if you're using [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) but it's kept me quite happy for years. According to the [Netbeans Docs](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/qt-applications.html), integrated Qt Designer support is available. I haven't tried it personally to see if it works from within a Python project but even if it doesn't I doubt the annoyance of launching Designer by hand would be sufficient to disuade you from using an otherwise excellent tool.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a built-in GUI builder for CPython.  You could use Jython + Matisse (the built-in Netbeans Java-based GUI builder).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not going to support dynamic languages in netbeans. In their marketing speak "dynamic languages on netbeans will be supported by the community" i.e. not by Oracle.

See [this webcast](http://oracle.com.edgesuite.net/ivt/4000/8104/9236/12627/lobby_external_flash_clean_480x360/default.htm) at time 11:55.

For the record, I used to use netbeans for python development and thought it was excellent but have now moved to eclipse + pydev.

Netbeans does have the "netbeans GUI Builder" but that is for the Java (or Jython) platform and does not support the common GUI frameworks used in python such as xwpython, Qt or Tkinter

Answer (score -1):

Is Google broken?

There's the first hit I got from Googling "Netbeans Python"

http://netbeans.org/features/python/index.html

I don't know what kind of "recommendation" you're looking for, but it's certainly supported.

Comment: It doesn't mention a GUI builder under Python.  I was hoping someone could tell me, because after my reading I wasn't sure, whether it has a GUI builder for Python.  And if it does have one, I was asking for opinions on it from people who know.

Comment: @ChrisC: Please UPDATE your question to very clearly state what you want to know.  I have no idea why anyone would want a GUI Builder since all it does is position the widgets incorrectly.  All GUI toolkits have layout rules that do a far, far better job than most folks can do manually.  Please define what your requirements are by UPDATING the question to say what you're trying to do.